# Using IF in a wrapper class

Tags: apex, wrapper-class

I have created a wrapper class which creates a record called Remittance_Advice_Line_Item__c, when a user selects a checkbox (called **selected**), and saves on a Visualforce page.

The record(s) that are created are populated with an amount, also entered by the user (called **pickedValue**).

There is a second checkbox on the page called **pickedCheck**, which if selected fires a process builder flow upon record creation. The purpose of the process builder is to overwrite the **pickedValue** on creation if this checkbox is selected.

I would like to incorporate the process in the class by means of an IF statement and I have attempted (see below), but I am not sure what the syntax would be to do so.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks...

```
public with sharing class ReconcileInvoicesController {

    public decimal pickedValue {get;set;}
    public String redirectUrl {get;set;}
    public String currentRecordID {get;set;}

    public List<wrapDeliveryNote> wrapDeliveryNoteList {get; set;}
    public List<Delivery_Note__c> selectedDeliveryNotes {get;set;}
    public Remittance_Advice__c CurrentRecordDetail {get;set;}

    public Remittance_Advice__c currentRecord {get;set;}

    public ReconcileInvoicesController() {

        currentRecord = [SELECT id,name,Account__r.name,Account__r.id,AccountId__c,Account__r.parentid FROM Remittance_Advice__c WHERE id = :ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('ID')];
        redirectUrl = '/'+currentRecord.Id;

        if(wrapDeliveryNoteList == null) {
            wrapDeliveryNoteList = new List<wrapDeliveryNote>();
            for(Delivery_Note__c d: [
                SELECT id,Name,zRemittancePositiveBalance__c,zRemittanceType__c FROM Delivery_Note__c WHERE AccountId__c = :currentRecord.AccountId__c
            ]){
                wrapDeliveryNoteList.add(new wrapDeliveryNote(d));
                }
        }
    }

    public void processSelected() {
        selectedDeliveryNotes = new List<Delivery_Note__c>();

        List<Remittance_Advice_Line_Item__c> remAdLineItemsTobeInserted = new List<Remittance_Advice_Line_Item__c>();
            for(wrapDeliveryNote wrapDeliveryNoteObj : wrapDeliveryNoteList) {
                if(wrapDeliveryNoteObj.selected == true) {
                    selectedDeliveryNotes.add(wrapDeliveryNoteObj.dn);

                    Remittance_Advice_Line_Item__c newRemItem = new Remittance_Advice_Line_Item__c();
                    newRemItem.Delivery_Note_Invoice__c = wrapDeliveryNoteObj.dn.Id;
                    newRemItem.Remittance_Advice__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

//REPLACE THIS
                    newRemItem.Remittance_Amount__c = wrapDeliveryNoteObj.pickedValue;

//WITH THIS
                    //  newRemItem.Remittance_Amount__c = IF(wrapDeliveryNoteObj.pickedCheck = TRUE,
                    //  wrapDeliveryNoteObj.dn.zRemittancePositiveBalance__c,
                    //  wrapDeliveryNoteObj.pickedValue);

                    newRemItem.Reconciles__c = wrapDeliveryNoteObj.pickedCheck;
                    newRemItem.Line_Item_Type__c = wrapDeliveryNoteObj.dn.zRemittanceType__c;

                    remAdLineItemsTobeInserted.add(newRemItem);
                }
            }
            if(remAdLineItemsTobeInserted.size() > 0){
                insert remAdLineItemsTobeInserted;
            }
        update selectedDeliveryNotes;
    }

    public class wrapDeliveryNote {
        public Delivery_Note__c dn {get;set;}
        public Boolean selected {get;set;}
        public decimal pickedValue {get;set;}
        public Boolean pickedCheck {get;set;}

        public wrapDeliveryNote(Delivery_Note__c d) {
            dn = d;
            selected = false;
            pickedValue = 0;
            pickedCheck = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ternary statement, which looks like `condition? value_when_true : value_when_false`.

---

```
newRemItem.Remittance_Amount__c = wrapDeliveryNoteObj.pickedCheck?
    wrapDeliveryNoteObj.dn.zRemittancePositiveBalance__c:
    wrapDeliveryNoteObj.pickedValue);
```

---

Comment: @TheMikeyBoosh you're welcome!